# Confusion in Pre-processing text for Roberta Model

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to apply Roberta model for  text similarity. Given a pair of sentences,the input should be in the format `<s> A </s></s> B </s>`. I figure out two possible ways to generate the input ids namely

a)

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')

list1 = tokenizer.encode('Very severe pain in hands')

list2 = tokenizer.encode('Numbness of upper limb')

sequence = list1+[2]+list2[1:]
```

In this case, sequence is `[0, 12178, 3814, 2400, 11, 1420, 2, 2, 234, 4179, 1825, 9, 2853, 29654, 2]`

b)

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')

list1 = tokenizer.encode('Very severe pain in hands', add_special_tokens=False)

list2 = tokenizer.encode('Numbness of upper limb', add_special_tokens=False)

sequence = [0]+list1+[2,2]+list2+[2]
```

In this case, sequence is `[0, 25101, 3814, 2400, 11, 1420, 2, 2, 487, 4179, 1825, 9, 2853, 29654, 2]`

Here `0` represents `<s>` token and 2 represents `</s>` token. I'm not sure which is the correct way to encode the given two sentences for calculating sentence similarity using Roberta model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to directly use the provided function by HuggingFace's Tokenizers themselves, namely the `text_pair` argument in the `encode` function, see [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.encode). This allows you to directly feed in two sentences, which will be giving you the desired output:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
sequence = tokenizer.encode(text='Very severe pain in hands',
                            text_pair='Numbness of upper limb',
                            add_special_tokens=True)
```

This is especially convenient if you are dealing with very long sequences, as the `encode` function automatically reduces your lengths according to the `truncaction_strategy` argument. You obviously don't have to worry about this, if it is only short sequences.

Alternatively, you can also make use of the more explicit [`build_inputs_with_special_tokens()`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/roberta.html#transformers.RobertaTokenizer.build_inputs_with_special_tokens) function of the `RobertaTokenizer`, specifically, which could be added to your example like so:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')

list1 = tokenizer.encode('Very severe pain in hands', add_special_tokens=False)
list2 = tokenizer.encode('Numbness of upper limb', add_special_tokens=False)

sequence = tokenizer.build_inputs_with_special_tokens(list1, list2)
```

Note that in that case, you have to generate the sequences `list1` and `list2` still *without* any special tokens, as you have already done correctly.